# loop break within loop python

Tags: python-2.7, loops

sorry i am a programming newbie and now stuck with a simple nested loop problem.

I am trying to write a very simple model for neutron propagation in 1D through a slab. the idea is i start at x0 = 0 and move the neutron forward a random distance, check if its absorbed or not, if not absorbed it again moves a random distance and i do this till is moves a distance xd = 10. Eventually the neutron goes to right of xd or left of xd or it is absorbed. I got a simple loop within loop problem for this. i am sure it has a simple solution just that i am not much into programing. following is the  code which i have written in python 2.7 so far.

```
    import random
    N = 100 # number of neutrons
    Nt= 0   # number of neutrons transmitted
    Na = 0  # number of neutrons absorbed
    Nr = 0 # number of neutrons reflected

    x0 = 0 
    xd = 10
    x = x0 #start position

    j = 1
    while j<= N #loop starts
        x+ = random.uniform(-1,1)
         if x > xd:
            Nt+ = 1
         elif x < x0:
            Nr+ = 1 
         else:
            gamma = random.uniform(0,1)
            if gamma <0.5:
            Na+ = 1
            else:
                continue # it should loop back and calculate x+=random.uniform(-1,1)
      x = x0
      j+= 1
    print Nr, Na, Nt
```

After the final else statement it has to loop back into the first if condition and continue to check the position of neutron. Obviously this is not happening here. What is the way to do it?

Comment: There is no loop present in your code. Suggest reading up [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_for_loop.htm)

Comment: i updated the code, after the final else statement it should loop back into the outer loop x+=random.uniform(-1,1)

Comment: Is your code not looping? You can remove the else and it should repeat the loop from the line x+=random. Do watch your indentation in python

Comment: There is a bug in your code, it not simulate N number of neutrons at the same time, it may stop before a single neutron dies. Read the comments in my code below. The idea is to repeat N times of a simulation of a neutron.

Comment: ok..i edited the code, i replaced break with continue. But now i am not sure what the code is doing really...

Comment: Suggest following a basic python tutorial on loops. You do not need an additional continue since it has reached the end of the block. Follow my code below to simulate 1 single neutron, once successful, add an outer loop to repeat N times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a loop to make it happen

```
import random
x0 = 0
xd = 10
x = x0 # start position

# simulates a single neutron, add an outer loop for N number of neutrons
while 1: #loops forever until explicit breaks
     x+ = random.uniform(-1,1) # move
     if x > xd:
        print 'neutron has transmitted'
        break # get out of loop
     if x < x0:
        print 'neutron has reflected'
        break # get out of loop

     if random.uniform(0,1) <0.5:
        print 'neutron has absorbed'
        break # get out of loop
     # at this point the loop repeats from the start
```

Comment: i updated the code, after the final else statement it should loop back into the outer loop x+= random.uniform(-1,1)